# How to find the smallest base in which p/q has a terminating expansion.

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

So I've looked at the examples $\frac{1}{192}$ where we needed to find a base which gave a terminating expansion with precisely 2 digits after the point, and $\frac{22}{675}$ where the digits after the point weren't specified. (Both fractions are in base 10 to start with.)

For $\frac{1}{192}$ the base was 24 and for $\frac{22}{675}$ it was 15 but I don't understand how they got to those answers.

Could somebody please explain or give me a generalised method to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: If the factorization of the denominator is $q=\prod_i p_i^{e_i}$, then the smallest base would be $\prod_i p_i$.

Comment: $\frac1{192}=0.001043_\text{six}$

Comment: Sorry, I missed the two digit constraint. Given that constraint, the base would be $\prod_i p_i^{\lceil e_i/2\rceil}$

Comment: $\frac{22}{675}=0.075_\text{fifteen}$ That looks like $3$ digits after the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of finding the smallest $b$ such that $\frac1{192}$ can be written in base $b$ with exactly $2$ digits is the problem of findint the smallest $b$ such that $\frac1{192}$ and be written as $\frac\alpha b+\frac\beta{b^2}$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}$ and $\beta>0$. But $\frac\alpha b+\frac\beta{b^2}=\frac{\alpha b+\beta}{b^2}$. Now, how can we write$$\frac{\alpha b+\beta}{b^2}=\frac1{192}?$$This implies that $192\mid b^2$. Since $192=2^6\times3$, the smallest perfect square which is a multiple of $192$ is $2^6\times3^2=576=24^2$. So, since$$\frac3{24^2}=\frac3{576}=\frac1{192},$$you take $b=24$.

Can you solve the other problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Look at $192=3\times 64 = 3^1\times 2^6$

$\cfrac 1{192}$ will have a terminating decimal in any base  which is divisible by $6=2\times 3$ because  $192 \times 3^5=6^6$ so that $\cfrac 1{192}=\cfrac{3^5}{6^6}$ and further note that this $=\cfrac {3}{2^63^2}=\cfrac {3}{24^2}$

Here I have cancelled what I can whilst leaving a square in the denominator (everything to an even power) - this is because I wanted a result with two digits. If I were looking for three digits I'd go for $$\frac {3^2}{2^63^3}=\frac 9{12^3}$$ so I would have a cube (the cube of the base) in the denominator.